# Do these two expressions describe the same $L^2$ norm?

Tags: normed-spaces, linear-control

In a lecture on model order reduction, the following expression is said to be equivalent to the $L^2$ norm of $h(t): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{r \times m}$, if $h(t) \rightarrow 0$ for $t \rightarrow \infty$.

$$
\left(
\int_0^\infty ||h(t - \tau)||^2_F d\tau
\right)^{1/2},
$$

where $||f||_F := \sqrt{\text{trace}(f^Tf)}$ is the Frobenius norm and the $L^2$ norm of $h(t)$ is elsewhere defined as

$$
||f(t)||_{L^2} =
\left(
\int_0^\infty||f(t)||^2_F dt
\right)^{1/2}.
$$

Is this correct? And if so, why?

Comment: neither are norms for functions defined for $t\in\mathbb R$?

Comment: what is "the Frobenius norm?"